# Best CodeMirror package for React with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, codemirror, react-codemirror

I was trying to implement a codeMirror in a existing react(with typescript) App. Can anyone please suggest a package that works fine with typescript as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image: npm version] [image: NPM Downloads]                                                                                                             [`#website`](https://uiwjs.github.io/react-codemirror/)

Github: https://github.com/uiwjs/react-codemirror

```
import React from 'react';
import CodeMirror from '@uiw/react-codemirror';
import { javascript } from '@codemirror/lang-javascript';

function App() {
  const onChange = React.useCallback((value, viewUpdate) => {
    console.log('value:', value);
  }, []);
  return (
    <CodeMirror
      value="console.log('hello world!');"
      height="200px"
      extensions={[javascript({ jsx: true })]}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
}
export default App;
```